# How to set different color theme for different Emacs frames?

Tags: macos, emacs, colors, text-editors

I prefer dark color themes for editing source codes while programming but I'd like to use a brighter background with black characters when writing text in org-mode. How can I set different color themes on different frames in Emacs? If I switch to another color theme, it changes across all frames.

I use GNU Emacs 23.1.1 on OS X 10.6.

Comment: Related: [Different color themes per mode in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532024/different-color-themes-per-mode-in-emacs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to the [solution in Juba's blog](http://blog.nozav.org/post/2010/02/10/Tangotango-emacs-color-theme). Package `color-theme` defines variable `color-theme-is-global` which decides if the given color theme should be installed on all frames or on only selected.

> A possible use for this variable is
>   dynamic binding. Here is a larger
>   example to put in your `~/.emacs`; it
>   will make the Blue Sea color theme the
>   default used for the first frame, and
>   it will create two additional frames
>   with different color themes.
>
> setup:
>
> ```
> (require 'color-theme)
> ;; set default color theme
> (color-theme-blue-sea)
> ;; create some frames with different color themes
> (let ((color-theme-is-global nil))
>   (select-frame (make-frame))
>   (color-theme-gnome2)
>   (select-frame (make-frame))
>   (color-theme-standard))
> ```