# How to set theme for each frame in Emacs 24

Tags: emacs, themes

I would like to set a different theme for each emacs window that I have open.

I want to use the new Emacs 24 theming, so I don't want to use the color-theme library as suggested in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/122086/how-to-set-different-color-theme-for-different-emacs-frames).

I am aware of load-theme-buffer-local command, but this sets the theme for that buffer, not for that window.

Is this possible? If so, how would I go about this?

Comment: Curious. Can you say why you want to use Emacs 24 custom themes instead of color themes?

Comment: @Drew Some of the Emacs 24 themes that I really like are not available in color-themes.

Comment: Got it.  Makes sense now.